# The nth term of the maclaurin sequence of $\frac 1{1+x+x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, euler-maclaurin

$$\frac 1{1+x+x^2}$$
$$ = \sum^\infty_{n=0} {(-1)}^n{(x+x^2)}^n$$
$$ = \sum^\infty_{n=0}{(-x)}^n \sum^n_{k=0} {_nC_k}x^k$$
$$ = \sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^{[\frac n2]}_{k=0}{(-1)}^{n-k}{_{n-k}C_k}x^n$$

I wanted to simplify the last expression to an expression with a single $\sum$.

So I tried substituting a few terms.

$$\begin{align}
\tag{n=6} \sum^3_{k=0}{(-1)}^{6-k}{_{6-k}C_k} = 1 \\
\tag{n=7} \sum^3_{k=0}{(-1)}^{7-k}{_{7-k}C_k} = -1 \\
\tag{n=8} \sum^4_{k=0}{(-1)}^{8-k}{_{8-k}C_k} = 0 \\
\tag{n=9} \sum^4_{k=0}{(-1)}^{9-k}{_{9-k}C_k} = 1 \\
\end{align} $$

Then, is there any generic simplified form of $\sum^{[\frac n2]}_{k=0}{(-1)}^{n-k}{_{n-k}C_k}x^n$?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053514/evaluates-n-binomn0-binomn-11-binomn-2n-3-binomn-3n-6/3054175#3054175 for a proof.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint for a simpler approach. Note that for $|x|<1$,
$$\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}=\frac{1-x}{1-x^3}=(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{3k}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Of course, You are a genius!!!! Thank you